# How can I resolve this error in shell scripting: "read: Illegal option -t"?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Hurry up and type something! > "
if read -t 10 response ; then
echo "Greate, you made it in time!"
else
echo "sorry, you are too slow!"
fi
```

I have written above code in terminal and got error "read: Illegal option -t".

Comment: I dont get any errors. works fine with `GNU bash, Version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I have got this error in ubuntu 12.10 32-bit pc

Comment: Check the version of bash you are using: `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash supports `-t`, so it looks like you're trying to execute it with `sh` or some other shell, which is odd, since you have the correct shebang.

Make sure you run it with `./script` or `path_to_script/script`. If you just run it in the terminal, first start `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and then I figured out that I was using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. After changing the shebang everything worked as desired.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` supports the `-t` option for the `read` builtin since version `bash-2.04` (see [ChangeLog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)), so either you are using an ancient version of `bash` (<= `2.03`) or are not really running your script under `bash`.

Run `bash --version` to check the version and double-check that your shebang really looks like `#!/bin/bash` in your script.