# Read command shows error as illegal option

Tags: bash, shell

The following is my code

```
Read file
Count=0
While read -n1 c
           Do
           Case $c in
            .
            .
            .
            .
            Esac
 Done < $file
 Echo"$count"
```

When I run this code, it shows the error as

> read: Illegal option -n

I'm just started learning shell programming.So please help me fix this code

Comment: All your keywords are invalid as they start with uppercase characters. Is this a copy-paste problem? Then, you maybe run your script with `sh` instead of Bash, and for example dash's `read` has no `-n` option.

Comment: The keywords itself turned itself into upper case because I posted this from my phone. And I ran the code in sh. Still the error exists

Comment: Yes, if you run it with `sh`, you use the `read` of whatever `sh` is (not necessarily Bash). On Ubuntu, for example, `sh` is dash, and the `read` of dash has no `-n` option. You probably want to run with `bash`. How exactly do you run your script? And does it have a shebang line?

Comment: I ran this code in Linux subsystem in windows which is as well Ubuntu. And no the code doesn't have a shebang line

Comment: What command are you using to run the script? I suspect `sh <scriptname>` instead of `bash <scriptname>`.

Comment: Yes I use sh -x <scriptname>

Comment: Now I used bash instead of sh, and it worked. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Or [How can I resolve this error in shell scripting: “read: Illegal option -t”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308913/how-resolved-this-error-in-shell-scripting-read-illegal-option-t)

Comment: The code worked on bash

Comment: Yes, I'm pointing to duplicate questions where people had the exact same problem: running a script with `read` and a Bash-specific option to it with a shell other than Bash.

Comment: Next time when posting to Stack Overflow, please copy your code directly. All CAPS for leading letter in a word isn't a good habit in programming :)

Answer (score 1):

`-n` is not an option for `read` in standard Unix `sh` and (some of) its variants.

`read -n` runs well on bash, zsh and ksh93, so you may want to select one of them instead of `sh` or `dash` (Debian `sh`), probably by adding a shebang line:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Or run explicitly with `bash`:

```
bash foo.sh
```