# How can I resolve this error in shell scipting: "read: Illegal option -s"?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter ur password"
read -s PASS
echo "ur password is $PASS"
```

I got the error "read: Illegal option -s".

Comment: POSIX shell's  `read` does not have `-s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as descripted by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308913/how-can-i-resolve-this-error-in-shell-scripting-read-illegal-option-t) , I solved this error by using `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`.It really worked !